# Launch Minecraft From Terminal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, Minecraft has been crashing on my Mac for a while, and I read somewhere that I have to put a certain command in Terminal and then run Minecraft from Terminal to get it to start. I have the command which I have to put in, but I don't have the second command, the one to get it to launch from Terminal. Does anyone have this command? Thanks!

Comment: The question is vague, and doesn't contain information. What command do you have, and which do you need?

Comment: Despite the vagueness, I too find it very difficult to find documentation to launch Minecraft from terminal, so I've voted this back up.  The software can be launched from terminal via the launcher provided in the `.app`'s `MacOS` folder.  @APCoding was pretty close and his technique should work, but launching the script directly is preferred for capturing stdout, etc.  The should eventually be improved further with Linux and Windows steps.

Answer (score 2):

These three commands should work for you:

1. `cd /`
2. `cd Applications`
3. `open Minecraft.app`

This assumes that you have Minecraft in your Applications folder. Also, make sure to run the commands separately, in the order listed above.

Answer (score 1):

**On Mac**

1. Open Spotlight (search in top right of desktop), Search for "Terminal".
2. Paste this into the Terminal:

   ```
   /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher
   ```

You will receive console logs that contain details about software activity.

When Minecraft crashes, it may provide a backtrace directly in the console or it may provide a crash log if the entire application crashes.  If the console doesn't show what you are looking for look for a recent `hs_err_pid*` file instead.  For more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8121186/3196753

Note, neither Microsoft, Mojang or Minecraft wiki mention running the software through terminal for debugging.  The official bug submission guidelines are provided here:

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/how-to-report-minecraft-bug