# Help with Minecraft LAN Server on Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, macos, hosting

My sister got Minecraft yesterday and we're unable to join each others' LAN servers. We're on the same Wi-Fi router, neither of us have firewalls blocking Java and have updated to the most recent version, we're both on the same version of Minecraft, etc. The other troubleshooting articles/questions I've seen are aimed at Windows users-- both of us are on OS X El Capitan. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Explain more on what won't work. I had this happen before to me, I took a computer to a friends house, and it wouldn't connect. I didn't look into fixing it though. Make sure it's the same version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 23):

In the launcher, go into the "Installations" tab. Choose a profile to patch. This method won't disrupt your game in any way, but if you're worried about breaking something, create a new installation.

Open the "More Options" panel, and paste the following text at the beginning of the "JVM Arguments" text field:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Mac is simply using iPv6 instead of iPv4 to try to connect to LAN worlds. The above text fixes that and forces it to prefer iPv4.

[image: example]

Comment: Much nicer than hacking the `Info.plist` file.  Thanks!  I've added this as the recommended method to the troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Don't forget to scroll down and hit Save after typing it in.

Comment: Note that "Advanced settings" needs to be enabled for JVM arguments.

Comment: I've just experienced similar problem (2019!) and adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to JVM arguments solved it! Obviously, the screenshot is out-of-date now but the solution works fine. Therefore, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: 2022, v1.19 and this still helpful, if you wonder.

Comment: 2023: press the triple dot on the right of the installation -> Edit -> More options. Then you'll get to the JVM args input.

Answer (score 16):

**Description**

Assuming you've done the normal troubleshooting (such as disabling the Firewall), you're experiencing bug with the networking protocol being used on MacOS (IPv6 versus IPv4), documented in detail here:

- https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-98598
- https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-101244
- ... also `MC-98499, MC-98772, MC-99283, MC-99419, MC-99884`

The fix is to tell Java to prefer IPv4.  This is not trivial as it requires forcing a `_JAVA_OPTION` override at launch (or system wide).

**Diagnose**

To diagnose this as the cause, first [launch Minecraft from terminal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320859/199492) with the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` overridden.

1. Close Minecraft
2. Open  Spotlight ( in upper right of Desktop)
3. Search for "Terminal", open the app
4. Paste the following command in:

   ```
   _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher
   ```
5. Attempt to connect to LAN server and see if it fixes the problem

**Permanently Fix**

**Using Minecraft Launch Options:** @TheOnlyMrCat provides a method [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322912/199492) that does not involve editing any files by hand.  Please try that before making changes to the Minecraft launcher.

**Patching the launcher manually**:

Use this method only if you have problems using @TheOnlyMrCat's solution.

This `_JAVA_OPTIONS` override can be provided [in many locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678) but since launching from Terminal is not ideal, we need to use a technique that fixes when clicking on the icon.  At time of posting, the Apple recommended method for providing overrides is inside the App bundle itself using something called [`LSEnvironment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-106825)

1. Optionally install a Text Editor such as [Atom](https://atom.io/) to edit XML files.
2. Using Finder, go to Applications
3. Locate (don't open) the Minecraft App
4. Right click Minecraft, Show Package Contents
5. Go into the `Contents` folder and locate `Info.plist`
6. Right click `Info.plist`, Open With, [Atom](https://atom.io/) (or TextEditor)
7. Near the bottom of the file, add the following in between the `<!-- ####`

   ```
   </dict>
   </plist>
       <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
       <string>YES</string>

       <!-- ######## ADD ONLY CONTENT BELOW THIS LINE ######## -->

       <key>LSEnvironment</key>
       <dict>
           <key>_JAVA_OPTIONS</key>
           <string>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</string>
       </dict>

       <!-- ######## ADD ONLY CONTENT ABOVE THIS LINE ######## -->

   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
8. Unfortunately this does not take effect right away.  This is due to the way Mac caches it's launch services.  Force refresh of the launch services using the following command from Terminal:

   ```
   cd /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/
   ./lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
   ```

   (Note, the path of `lsregister` may be different, you can find it using `find /System -name lsregister`)
9. Launch Minecraft from the icon and search for LAN games to confirm that the fix was properly applied.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Btw it looks like the path for lsregister may change slightly depending on OS X version.  I ended up locating it with `find /System -name lsregister`

Comment: This is great, the 'lsregister` command should be called with:
```./lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user``` (Note the `./` at the beginning of the command.)

Comment: @disperse, done because it's slightly better.  Note, on dozens of Macs ranging from 10.7 - 10.13, `lsregister` wasn't on the `$PATH`, so the original version shouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac computer you want to host, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then select 'Open to LAN'.

[image: Open to LAN]

Then on the Mac you will be joining the game, select 'Multiplayer' from the main menu and you will see the game which you can then join.

[image: Game to Join]

If you've done these steps and are getting an error when trying to join the game, please edit that error into your question.

Comment: Your response is not about minecraft server.  You are getting "lan sharing" on the non-server version confused with running a minecraft server.

Comment: @TomHallan the question specifically asks about a LAN server -- I know the difference between Minecraft Server and sharing a world via LAN.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to find the IP Address of the host, and then use the use Direct Connect to connect to the server.

To find your IP address on Mac, go to the Apple Logo button on the top left of the menu bar > About This Mac, and in that window that pops up there will be a button with the text "System Report". Click on that and it will open the System Information, and then in the Network tab it will show you your IP address. When you 'Start LAN game' on the host computer, a port number will show up in the chat. That will also be important. To connect to your LAN game, type the IP address into Direct Connect on another computer, followed by the Port Number, in this order (include the colon):

*IP ADRESS*:*PORT NUMBER*

Have fun!

Answer (score -3):

You both may need to download a program called LogMeIn Hamachi which is free and will allow you to connect.

Since you guys are using the same IP address, it won't let you connect. Without Hamachi, you can't connect from long distances; LAN stands for **local** area network.

With both of you using Hamachi, you can play. Its what I use. Look up instructions on how to use Hamachi, if you get confused.

Comment: We tend to expect better quality than "use this, and look up for yourself how to use it". Could you provide more detail on how Hamachi actually fixes this problem?

Comment: Hamachi is used to simulate a LAN network over the internet. While it's possible it would also work around the IP4 problems when Hamachi is used by two people on the same intranet, it is definitely overkill.