# Can Windows and Mac connect to the same LAN Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My sister, on a Windows, is trying to connect to my LAN server and I'm on a Mac. Can we connect with each other?

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Comment: @Kez can you please write  an actual answer with details?

Comment: @Kez Can you? I thought the only way you could was with the Better Together edition. If both were just running the Java client I dont think it would be possible. I could be wrong, often am, just thought that was the whole purpose of that edition was to support this kind of thing.

Comment: It's a simple answer. @200Ethan gave a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

OS will not halt any way to connect via LAN. Computers with the Java edition of Minecraft can connect to each other. Devices with the Bedrock/Windows 10/Pocket Edition of Minecraft can connect to each other. However, Bedrock and Java editions are different, and therefore incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the type of OS that you have should not determine the type of server you will be able to join, as long as both games are useable on their respective OS.

Some things that could come into play though, considering it is on LAN, are firewalls, and other 'blocking/monitoring' software on either computer.

Here is a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1z8201/connecting_pc_to_mac_via_lan/) about some suggestions and tips, and [here is a previous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267467/help-with-minecraft-lan-server-on-mac) Gaming Exchange question and answers. Hope it helps!